# What are the necessary minimal permissions to have Apache Camel working with Amazon S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

I'm trying to make an application with Apache Camel + Amazon S3. Just a simple case where a file will be received by an endpoint and will be processed and sent to a S3 bucket.

```
s3.bucket=my-bucket
camel.component.aws2-s3.access-key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
camel.component.aws2-s3.secret-key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
camel.component.aws2-s3.region=${AWS_REGION:us-east-2}


from("direct:s3")
        .log(INFO, log, "Sending to S3")
        .process(S3Processor())
        .to("aws2-s3://${properties.s3Bucket}?multiPartUpload=true&partSize=10485760")
```

When I give my user S3:* permissions, everything works just fine. But I'm finding hard to "fine tune" those permissions. Whenever I try to use the bare minimum, something like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'll get a S3 error when launching my app:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route3 because of null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:123) ~[camel-base-engine-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:306) ~[camel-base-engine-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:189) ~[camel-base-engine-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147) ~[camel-base-engine-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:3166) ~[camel-base-engine-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2846) ~[camel-base-engine-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2797) ~[camel-base-engine-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43) ~[camel-spring-boot-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119) ~[camel-api-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2494) ~[camel-base-engine-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:245) ~[camel-core-engine-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:119) ~[camel-spring-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:151) ~[camel-spring-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at net.myapp.RouterApplicationKt.main(RouterApplication.kt:15) ~[main/:na]
```

I couldn't find anywhere listing the minimal permissions that my user should have.
Does anybody know what are those permissions?

Ah, before anyone asks, with just **s3:PutObject** permission, I can upload a file to my bucket using the aws command line client.

[]'s

Comment: Could you please post the full stacktrace ? as text instead of an image?

Answer (score 1):

After narrowing down loads of permission combinations, I end up with the same as in the beginning:

```
"Action": [
    "s3:PutObject",
    "s3:ListBucket"
]
```

The only difference is that, I also limited my scope to a single bucket instead of using an all bucket arn ("Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*/*").